# SQL: OPENQUERY Question

Tags: sql-server-2008, openquery

I am currently using OPENQUERY to import Data into a Database from an Oracle Linked Server.

I am currently using SELECT INTO.  It works well, but I have to drop the database and recreate it everytime i need to import the data or else i get the error: Table Already exists.

Is there another way to work with OPENQUERY which will import the data without having to Drop and recreate the table that i need?

Here is what i Have:

SELECT
      *
INTO
      TEMPTBL
FROM  OPENQUERY(LINK, 'SELECT * FROM DATALOAD')

Thanks.

Comment: drop the table not the database right?

Comment: right, i am having to drop the table after each import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?
INSERT INTO PERMTBL (column list)  SELECT (column list) FROM OPENQUERY(LINK, 'SELECT (column list)  FROM DATALOAD')